# AWS s3 image put object

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to decode image from base64 to byte array and load into S3 bucket. Bellow is my code,

```
 byte[] imagecontent = Base64.decodeBase64(IMMAGE_CONTENT);
if(imagecontent .length>0) {

       input = new ByteArrayInputStream(screenshot);    
       String file_name = "img_SOME_LOGIC.jpg";
       conn.putObject( this.bucketname, file_name, input, new ObjectMetadata());

}
```

Above code is working fine for text documents. meaning reading text file and uploading. However above is not working for image.
Following is the error i got,

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to unmarshall error response (The declaration for the entity "ContentType" must end with '>'.)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:283)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:168)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2555)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1044)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:928)
```

Can you please help me ?

**UPDATED:**

```
[Fatal Error] strict.dtd:81:5: The declaration for the entity "ContentType" must end with '>'.
97943 [Thread-62-s3store-executor[20 20]] ERROR c.a.h.AmazonHttpClient - Unable to unmarshall error response (The declaration for the entity "ContentType" must end with '>'.)
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The declaration for the entity "ContentType" must end with '>'.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:?]
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at com.amazonaws.util.XpathUtils.documentFrom(XpathUtils.java:67) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.2.15.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3ErrorResponseHandler.handle(S3ErrorResponseHandler.java:63) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.2.15.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3ErrorResponseHandler.handle(S3ErrorResponseHandler.java:38) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.2.15.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:516) [aws-java-sdk-1.2.15.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:283) [aws-java-sdk-1.2.15.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:168) [aws-java-sdk-1.2.15.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2555) [aws-java-sdk-1.2.15.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1044) [aws-java-sdk-1.2.15.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:928) [aws-java-sdk-1.2.15.jar:?]
    at com.bgt.aggregation.bolt.s3bolt.execute(s3bolt.java:171) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5044$tuple_action_fn__5046.invoke(executor.clj:727) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__4965.invoke(executor.clj:459) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__4480.onEvent(disruptor.clj:40) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:472) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:451) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:73) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5044$fn__5057$fn__5110.invoke(executor.clj:846) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__557.invoke(util.clj:484) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_112]
```

Comment: Are you behind some kind of a proxy? It seems that the AWS Client doesn't allow HTTP connections, but HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you @TenorFlyy, But the above code works fine when i upload text file.

Comment: Sure that is my bad, sorry. Do you have some logs by any chance?

Comment: @TenorFlyy - yes  please see the updated section

Comment: Please add the code used to create the `AmazonHttpClient` instance.

Comment: I see a few possible solutions to your specific error, but I doubt any of them would work, guess you have tried googling them yourself. 

One other thing I see is that you don't setup the `contentType` of your metadata anywhere.

You can try specifying it explicitly like this:

`metadata.setContentType("image/jpg");`

Comment: ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
  clientConfig.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);
  this.conn = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, clientConfig);

Comment: @TenorFlyy - Above code is used for creating connetion

Comment: Btw, I've made a typo on the previous comment, it should be "image/jpeg". Could you please try setting this up as the SDK will try to manually determine the type and it is possible that it messes things up. Also, if it is an option, please do give it a shot using HTTPS and comment with the results.

Comment: @TenorFlyy - Worked fine now. My bad i missed that part. It should be HTTPS.  Can you add your answer so that i mark your answer accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using HTTPS instead of HTTP. AWS Client seems to be having issues with HTTP.